# Flowplayer Playlist & HTML5 Fallback

Tags: html, audio, rtmp, flowplayer, playlist

I currently have a flowplayer set up that uses the RTMP plugin and streams 3 files one after the other (a playlist). Currently I only have the flash version of the player doing this but I would like to somehow do the same thing for a HTML5 fallback for iPads, iPhones & Android.

I managed to get it so there was a HTML5 audio player playing one of the files but it needs to play all 3 one after each other.

Firstly, is this possible? Secondly, would there be anyone that can help me code this for a page as I don't really have a great deal of knowledge doing this.

I'd also like to switch the flash version over to HTTP rather than RTMP.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

HTML `<audio>` does not offer internal playlist capabilities.

What you need to do is to

- Write your playlist into Javascript array
- Listen to `<audio>` **ended** media event
- Set `<audio src>` to next item on the playlist in your event handler

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Media_events

Comment: Thanks, however I haven't got a clue where to start with that!

Comment: If you do not posses low level Javascript skills to make it happen, maybe you can try alternative well-documented Javascript library which should have playlist capability http://mediaelementjs.com/